# WPF DatePicker, Setting CalendarBlackoutDatesCollection with Style

Tags: wpf, xaml, datepicker, styles

I need to limit the date range of all `DatePicker` controls in an existing WPF application to limit input errors by users.

I thought about using a global style similar to this:

```
<Style TargetType="DatePicker">
    <Setter Property="CalendarBlackoutDatesCollection">
        <Setter.Value>               
            <CalendarDateRange Start="1/1/1999" End="1/1/2100"/>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

But I can not find the right way to define this. Can someone give me a hint how to achive this? It should be a solution to control this behavior a one point for all `DatePicker`s of the app.

Answer (score 0):

The blackout dates define dates that should be crossed out and not selectable. I guess that you meant to allow dates that fall into the defined range only. In order to do that, define a [`DisplayDateStart`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.datepicker.displaydatestart?view=netcore-3.1) and a [`DisplayDateEnd`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.datepicker.displaydateend?view=netcore-3.1).

```
<Style x:Key="MyDatePickerStyle"  TargetType="{x:Type DatePicker}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type DatePicker}}">
   <Setter Property="DisplayDateStart" Value="1/1/1999"/>
   <Setter Property="DisplayDateEnd" Value="1/1/2100"/>
</Style>
```

Reference this style in each `DatePicker` that you want to limit the date range for.

```
<DatePicker Style="{StaticResource MyDatePickerStyle}"/>
```

If you want to apply the style to all `DatePicker`s automatically in the scope where the style is defined without having to specify the `Style` on each one manually, you can remove the `x:Key` from the style to make it a so called *implicit style*.

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type DatePicker}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type DatePicker}}">
```

If you want to apply the style to all `DatePicker`s, define it in the application resources.